# ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats: Increase font size in p-values in comparisons in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, size, p-value

First of all, I apologize for my poor English.

I am using `ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats` to compare my groups. However, I noticed that font size in *p*-values from these comparisons is small. Thus, I would like to ask some help to increase font size in these *p*-values. I will post my script using data from "Edgar Anderson's Iris Data" as example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RVAideMemoire)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggstatsplot)

iris.table <- iris

ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(data = iris.table, x = class, y = sepal_l, plot.type = "box", type = "parametric", k = 3, outlier.tagging = FALSE, mean.plotting = FALSE, xlab = "Species", ylab = "Sepal Length", ggstatsplot.layer = FALSE, pairwise.comparisons = TRUE, pairwise.display = "significant", p.adjust.method = "BH", point.args = list(position = ggplot2::position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.15), size = 1.5, stroke = 0))+
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black", "black"))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Iris setosa", "Iris versicolor", "Iris virginica"))+
  theme(text = element_text(size=13), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12), axis.text = element_text(size = 13), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), plot.caption = element_text(size = 13), plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 13))
```

[image: My Plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed not straightforward to do with the current implementation.

I have added a new argument to change the aesthetics related to pairwise comparison geom now. Once you download `ggstatsplot` from [GitHub](https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot), you can do something like the following:

```
set.seed(123)
library(ggstatsplot)

ggbetweenstats(
  iris, Species, Sepal.Length,
  pairwise.comparisons = TRUE,
  ggsignif.args = list(textsize = 6, tip_length = 0.01)
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Comment: Is there a method to display less texts in the subtitle? for example, I want to show only p value in the subtitle, others such as confidence interval and t and g values are not needed.

Comment: Same as: https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/issues/669

I might add support for this in the future releases.